# How to unwrap a plane with displacement and a hole in the middle without stretching

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a plane (ground) with a hole in it. The plane has a displacement modifier in it.

[image: Stretched UvMap]

the thing is that the uv unwraping gets stretched no matter what i do.

What can i do to make it right?

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could show what effect it is you're trying to achieve with a reference image. You're going to get distortion and stretching of some form as you're transitioning from a flat topology to a cylinder.

Comment: As Rich already mentioned, seams will be unavoidabe as the texture otherwise is bound to stretch. The seams you placed work already anyways, the only real distorsion that I can see comes from both Displacement modifiers. They just deform the mesh too much in the area of the fillet between cylinder and plane. The Unwrapping happens before the modifiers come into play, so any deformation, displacement, even the multires are going to affect it. If you feel that this is the problem, you can re-unwrap after applying these modifiers, even though that's not great fun sometimes.

Comment: You're right @RichSedman I could be more specific. My problem as aliasguru said has to do with the border stretch distortion just after it becomes a cylinder.

Comment: Thanks @aliasguru. I will try applying the modifiers first, I'm sure there will be no problem with that. I assumed that if I enabled the "Display modifier in Edit Mode" and  the "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" in the modifier properties some how it would affect the uv unwrapping and avoid the "apply modifier" procedure. Thank you both for your answers.